# boolean logic expression: start_addr = stop_addr & ~mask

Tags: logic

Let's say you have the following boolean expression of 16 bit words:

```
start_addr  = stop_addr & ~mask
```

Where:  start_addr < stop_addr

example:

```
0xAA00 = 0xAAFF & ~0x00FF
0xAA00 = 0xAAFF & 0xFF00
0xAA00 = 0AA00
```

now, suppose, I know only start_addr, and stop_addr, and mask is unknown.  How to find mask?

Comment: In general you can't with one known example. If start is `0xAA00` and stop is `0xAA01` and this is the only known example, then you can't tell whether the mask is `0x0001`, `0x0003` or `0x55FF`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
start_addr = stop_addr + -mask

mask = stop_addr - start_addr

mask = 0xAAFF - 0xAA00 

mask = 0xFF
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you want is that given `start_addr` and `stop_addr`, then it is not always possible to determine `mask`.

For some values of `start_addr` and `stop_addr` it can happen that there is no `mask` satisfying the equation, for others may be several possible values of `mask` satisfiyng the equation.